# Is there any benefits to using List.AddRange over a LINQ.ToList()?

Tags: c#

I was working through an MVC4 tutorial today and saw the user implemented a select in a different manner than I'm used to.  His code was:

```
var GenreLst = new List<string>(); 

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies 
               orderby d.Genre 
               select d.Genre; 
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct()); 
ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);
```

I looked at it and rewrote it in my own way as:

```
var genres = db.Movies
            .OrderBy(m => m.Genre)
            .Select(m => m.Genre)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

ViewBag.MovieGenre = new SelectList(genres);
```

His GenreList variable isn't used elsewhere, so I got rid of it.  My main question is how he uses the AddRange.  Is it any better to AddRange than ToList?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Well, `AddRange` lets you add items to an existing list. `ToList` doesn't.

Comment: @TimSchmelter AddRange is smart enough to look at the number of items being added in the range, and increase the size of the buffer once, by enough.  You'll still be allocating the default size 10 buffer and not using it, but you won't be re-allocating lots of buffers.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, just deleted my comment. It cannot look at the number if the query is not executed, just if it can be casted to an `ICollection<T>`. Otherwise it must be executed and enumerated. The size is unknown until end in that case and the list might be twice as large as needed..

Comment: @TimSchmelter If it's not actually an `IList` then the constructor won't know the size either, so it will work just the same way.  Clearly the programmer isn't manually entering a size, so he doesn't know at compile time what the [approximate] size will be.

Comment: @Sery: Yes, that's not usual but what i wanted to say is, it's possible that there's a difference. `var range=Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000);List<int> list=range.ToList()` actually is much less efficient than `list=new List<int>(10000000);list.AddRange(range)` and even less efficient than `list=new List<int>(range.Count());list.AddRange(range)`(since the latter will ensure that the list is not larger than necessary).

Comment: What I don't get is why is there a list at all?  The SelectList constructor takes IEnumerable.  Is it just to guarantee that the query is only executed once?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`e.ToList<T>()` is implemented under the hood as:

```
return new List<T>(e);
```

And the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T> e)` constructor actually just calls `this.AddRange(e)` internally.

In other words, the two bits of code will do the exact same thing, in the exact same way.