# Would AddRange() be faster than ToList() in this case?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a comma delimited string called `ctext` which I want to split and put into a `List<string>`.

Would using LINQ,

```
List<string> f = ctext.Split(',').ToList();
```

be slower than not using LINQ?

```
List<string> f;
f.AddRange(ctext.Split(','));
```

It seems that LINQ would actually copy something somewhere at some point which would make it slower, whereas `AddRange()` would just check the size of the list once, expand it, and dump it in.

Or is there an even faster way? (Like using a `for` loop, but I doubt it.)

Comment: Why are these the only options? What about `new List(ctext.Split(','))`?

Comment: Both `ToList` and `AddRange` make copies. If you want to know which is faster, run them moth and measure.

Comment: Will do @DStanley.

Comment: That's apples and oranges. One creates a list, the other throws a NullReferenceException. Anyhow, exception handling is slower than you think.

Comment: And thanks for pointing me in the right direction @JacobKrall.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547143) may help as well.

Comment: @skwear "No discernible difference" is probably the answer. If one or the other is appreciably faster, why wouldn't the .NET guys have noticed that by now (it's been years and years) and fixed the slow one to do it right?

Comment: 99% of the time "which is faster..." questions are answered by "measure it!" As @DStanley suggests, run them moth. :) Couldn't resist!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I'm going to go with the constructor way `new List<string>(ctext.Split(','))` as suggested by Jacob Krall and the venerable Jon Skeet. Basically what I was thinking of doing, but in a cleaner fashion. Will definitely be measuring it.

Comment: @n8wrl [This](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is my inspiration for that answer...

Comment: @skwear Jon didn't actually suggest doing that, he just said that's what `ToList` does internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, we can easily look at what [`ToList`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs#L22) does now that it's open source. (Follow the link for the latest source...)

I haven't seen `IListProvider<T>` before, but I doubt that an array implements it, which means we've basically got `new List<TSource>(source)`. Looking at the [`List<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs) source shows that both the constructor and `AddRange` basically end up using `CopyTo`.

In other words, other than a few levels of indirection, I'd expect them both to do the same thing.

Comment: Github source code is same as one listed on referencesource.microsoft.com, or is there a preference in terms of reliability.

Comment: @Mrinal: I don't know for sure. I'm just more familiar with navigating github.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that LINQ would actually copy something somewhere at some point which would make it slower, whereas AddRange() would just check the size of the list once, expand it, and dump it in.

You are correct that both of these things are happening, but incorrect in thinking that each are specific to that one operation.  Both `ToList` and `AddRange` do both of those things.  Both operations copy all of the values from the input sequence into the list, and since both of them are adding multiple items at the same time they're able to see how much to expand the internal capacity of the list all at once, rather than needing to perform multiple expansions.